# templeate not found in flask

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='home/root13/webapp.html/staic/')



@app.route("/index.html")

def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/home")

def hello_world():
    return render_template('post.html')



if __name__ == "__main__":

   app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flask will try to find the HTML file in the templates folder, in the same folder in which this script is present.

```
-Application folder
  -Hello.py
  -templates
    -hello.html
```

You should put all HTML files inside a folder named **templates**

Comment: What if you override the template folder like in the question?